# How can I see values of Object in NSLog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, nslog

Suppose I have an object containing some data.

How can I see that data using NSLog?

If anyone is not clear about my question, then can ask me again.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to see an NSArray and NSDictionary and etc objects then you can directly print like `NSLog(@"%@",object);`

If it is an user defined object then you need to display by calling with property (attribute).

User defined object with name object and properties like

```
NSString *property1;
int property2;
NSMutableArray *property3;
```

Print them in the console as follows:

`NSLog(@"%@, %d, %@" object.property1,object.property2,object.property3);`

Answer (score 20):

If you implement the `-(NSString*)description` method in your class then you can use `NSLog` to output a summary of the data. Of course, you can also directly output any property.

For example:

```
NSLog (@"%@ %d", object, object.integer);
```

The first part calls the `description` method and outputs that; the second part gets the value of the integer property of object and outputs that.

Comment: I knew I have to implement a function to get it printed. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Upvoted. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Every Objective-c Object (this comes from NSObject) has a property called `description`. So if you want to print information about your class this is the way to go.

```
@implementation MyClass

- (NSString*)description
{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyClass:%@", @"This is my class"];
}
```

so if you do a call like this.

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", myClass);
NSLog(@"%@", [myClass description]); //Same as the line above
```

Then it will write `"MyClass:This is my class"` to the console (in this case it will print it twice).

Answer (score 10):

Implement **`description`** of the given class.

```
-(NSString*)description {

    return [NSString
            stringWithFormat:@"<%@> name: `%@` size: `%@`",
            NSStringFromClass(self), self.name,
            NSStringFromCGSize(self.size)];
}

NSLog(@"%@", object); // <Object> name: `Harry` size: `{2, 2}`
```

---

```
extension Object: CustomStringConvertible {
    
    var description: String {
        "<\(Self.self)> name: `\(name)` size: `\(size)`"
    }
}

print(object) // <Object> name: `Harry` size: `(2.0, 2.0)`
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest these:

**Objects:**

For objects like Dictionary,  Array, Strings do it like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", object);
```

For basic data-types like integers

```
NSLog(@"%i",intVal);
```

For type encoding you should see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html

Answer (score 2):

Use this class https://github.com/arundevma/ICHObjectPrinter

`NSLog(@"Object description is %@",[ICHObjectPrinter descriptionForObject:person]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"My object data:%@",[myObj someData]);
NSLog(@"My object Other data:%@",[myObj someOtherData]);
```

Or directly:

```
NSLog(@"%@",myObj);
NSLog(@"Description:%@",[myObj description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Satya's answer, if you want to see basic c data types, use the format specifiers. Such as %d for an integer:

```
NSLog (@"My integer:%d", myObject.myInteger);
```

The complete list is here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/